# Pattern Is Matching Every Other Line Of Input

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the pattern I have:

```
\s+\d+:\s+(?<local>\d+)[-][>]\s+?(?<remote>\d+)\s+(?<wwn>..:..:..:..:..:..:..:..)\s+\d+\s+(?<name>\w+)\s+[s][p]:\s+\w+.\w+\s+\w+[:]\s+\d.\w+\s+(?<trunk>TRUNK)?
```

Here is the input.  The '*' is not part of the input, it's just designating what is matched.  I'm testing this at RegExStorm.net.  I don't think the every other line is significant by itself, different input didn't follow with matching every other line.  I can't see what's different, if anything between the matched and non-match lines except for the line that says QOS but the match should still succeed there, it would just throw that away.

```
 *  1:  0-> 11 10:00:00:05:1e:89:ed:8c  14 SAN009B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
  2: 23->  2 50:00:51:e8:b9:1b:ae:01   3 fcr_fd_3        sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
 * 3: 24-> 22 10:00:00:05:1e:36:5b:ea   1 SAN001B         sp:  4.000G bw:  4.000G TRUNK 
  4: 38-> 38 10:00:00:05:1e:e2:45:00   9 SAN004B         sp:  8.000G bw: 24.000G TRUNK QOS 
 *5: 48-> 15 10:00:00:05:1e:89:ed:8c  14 SAN009B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
 6: 49-> 10 10:00:00:05:1e:87:5a:e4  13 SAN013B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
 *7: 56->  3 10:00:00:05:1e:84:15:dc  11 SAN011B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
 8: 64-> 16 10:00:00:05:1e:89:ed:8c  14 SAN009B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
* 9: 65-> 18 10:00:00:05:1e:87:5a:e4  13 SAN013B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
10: 72-> 63 10:00:00:05:1e:84:15:dc  11 SAN011B         sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
*11: 87-> 27 50:00:51:e8:b9:1b:ae:01   3 fcr_fd_3        sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of this part: `\d.\w+`

The corresponding part for the other number is `\w+.\w+`

`24` (from the `24.000G` substring) does not fit the `\d`, so you either should use `\d+` or `\w+`.

Another note, in this excerpt it you want to use the dot literal as-is, you need to escape it as `\.`, since otherwise it matches `any character`.

How I found your problem: I opened it on https://regex101.com/ and removed the parts from the regular expression until it matched, then it was immediately obvious.

Comment: That's a handy site.  I've bookmarked it.  I like that it handles named groups.   I was able to figure out that the leading \s+ was messing up some of the matches.

Comment: I'd like to know why that leading '\s+' was messing up the matches.  Is RegEx trying to match spaces that fall before that \s?

Comment: @DavidGreen create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The smaller the example - the easier it is to deal with/explain it to self.

Comment: I think I figured it out using regex101.  thanks for that site, it's better than regexstorm that I've been using.